# How do I mark up a list of labels and values, some of which are editable?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-markup

In our application, there are several pages where users see a list of attributes of something, some of which they can edit. These pages usually have a header, and then a list of labels and values. The first few aren't editable; usually these are things like metadata or a name/id that nobody but the sysadmin can change.

What's the best way to mark this up?

A couple ideas that I had right away were to just use a form and set up the read-only values as read-only fields:

```
<h1>Title of the page</h1>
<form action="whatever" method="whatever">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="readonly-1" class="control-label">Event name</label>
    <input id="readonly-1" type="text" readonly class="form-control" value="HTML Party">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="readonly-2" class="control-label">Created by</label>
    <input type="text" id="readonly-2" readonly value="Nate Green">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="editable-1" class="control-label">Event date</label>
    <input type="date" id="editable-1" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="editable-2" class="control-label">Location</label>
    <select multiple type="date" id="editable-2" class="form-control">
      <option selected value="CLE">Cleveland</option>
      <option value="NYC">New York City</option>
      <option value="ORD">Chicago</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

...but I'd really rather not have all the read-only values look/act like form fields, if I can help it. (Perhaps that *is* the best way to do it, and now I just have to style them the way I want with CSS?)

I also thought of marking it up as a definition list, like so:

```
<h1>Title of the page</h1>
<dl>
  <dt>Event name</dt>
  <dd>HTML Party</dd>
  <dt>Created by</dt>
  <dd>Nate Green</dd>
</dl>
<form action="whatever" method="whatever">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="editable-1" class="control-label">Event date</label>
    <input type="date" id="editable-1" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="editable-2" class="control-label">Location</label>
    <select multiple type="date" id="editable-2" class="form-control">
      <option selected value="CLE">Cleveland</option>
      <option value="NYC">New York City</option>
      <option value="ORD">Chicago</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, I don't think we could safely say that there would never be read-only values *between* two editable ones, and it also feels wrong to have a `<dl>` element with only one pair of `<dt>` and `<dd>`s.

Surely someone else has solved a problem like this before. How would you recommend we approach this?

Comment: "I don't think we could safely say that there would never be read-only values between two editable ones": Could this change per user/item on the fly, or would you know beforehand? Couldn’t you simply organize the page in two parts: here are the things you might want to know but can’t edit, and here is a form with things you can edit? For example, in a user profile the user can edit their email address, but not the registration date. In such a case there is no need to display these two things in a similar way.

Comment: @unor On some pages, things make more sense if they appear in a certain order, which is kind of agnostic of whether the fields can be edited or not. An example is a page where the user has just uploaded a file, and now they have to set certain metadata about it. The order of things on a page might be Name*, Label, Type*, Control type. (* means it's read-only.) It makes more sense for Name (a property from the file uploaded) and Label to be together, and it makes more sense for the "type" from the file and the "control type" to be together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically is not wrong to put the values in a readonly field. `<dd>` and `<dt>` are not for this purposes, since you can use it with no problems, are not a term-definition combo.

You can stylize the readonly inputs to show like a text and you'll achieve that with pure CSS:

```css
input[readonly] {
  border:0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 ;
  padding: 0;
  /* for mobile! */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input value="This is editable">
<br>
<input value="this is readonly" readonly>
```

By this method, you don't have to change the HTML markup, only add the `readonly` property when you need.

Comment: Thanks! FYI, though: `<dl>`s aren't defined as only for terms and definitions anymore—[they're now called "description lists"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl), and the spec says they're appropriate for any type of key-value relationship.

Comment: Also, I didn't say explicitly that we are using Twitter Bootstrap (my bad) but we are, and TWBS actually styles `<dl>`s to look *mostly* like their form controls/labels by default, so that's part of the reason I thought the `<dl>` would be a viable option.

Comment: Ok, if you like that tags use them. I don't know now what is the question.

Comment: I think is better the `readonly` method because you don't have to make different views to same screen

Comment: Fair point. :) The question was "how do I mark this up," so you've answered it. I was looking for a strong argument for using one method or the other, or a different method I hadn't considered. So, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If I need to make something similar, it's probably I make with this method, at least if I don't have any other functionality or reason.

Comment: I'm going to wait a day or two but if nobody else chimes in, I will accept your answer. :)